# Weird browser behaviour when deleting, what can I do to work around this?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, contenteditable, nicedit

**TLDR**
Open this up in IE8 http://jsbin.com/ucahor/1/edit#/ucahor/2/edit
Click on a blank line and immediately press `Backspace`. 2 lines are deleted.
Click on a blank line, wait a second then press `Backspace`. 1 line is deleted.
Is there anything I can do to work around this?

**Full story**
I'm trying to make the best possible rich text editor for my web application. I've taken [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com) and added a bunch of functionality. I'm using nicedit because it was the only editor that satisfied these requirements from the 9 I tested.

- Works in IE6
- Can paste from Word
- Numbering and bullets
- Pure Javascript (so we can modify it easily)
- Small number of files downloaded
- Can set the cursor position
- Can be fullscreened
- Can handle large files (1500 paragraphs pasted)

One thing I added to my implementation of NicEdit is to have headings inserted for common reports that my users write. A problem with this is that I need a way of having blank lines between the headers. I cannot use `<br/>` tags because they do not play nicely with inserting lists and I cannot use `<div>` tags because internet explorer has issues with divs inside a content editable div.

This leaves me with using the `<p>` tag for indicating new lines.

However I can't just use `<p></p>`, it is an HTML standard for user agents to ignore empty `P` tags.

Currently my users are getting by with `<p>&nbsp;</p>` but this indents every line with a space and new lines do not have the space.

I discovered that there is a `Zero Width Space` character `&#8203;` that will allow my `P` tags to be rendered and not have a space on each line!

My new `<p>&#8203;</p>` works well except if a user is deleting a line the first backspace appears to do nothing.

So I bound to my keydown event for backspace. It checks the character before the cursor, if it is my `Zero Width Space` character I blank it out and let the backspace continue as normal.

This works, except if you click the line you wish to delete and quickly click backspace. That action causes 2 lines to be deleted.

You can load up your IE8 and try it out here. http://jsbin.com/ucahor/1/edit#/ucahor/2/edit

Comment: What constitutes your "headers," just being bold?  If so, I can add linebreaks on the nicedit example here http://nicedit.com/ without issue.  It adds `<DIV>`s, instead of `<P>`s, though.  Have you tried tinyMCE?  I believe it satisfies all of your requirements.

Comment: @user1477388 You may be using a different browser. In IE8 line breaks are `<p>`. TinyMCE was very close (it was in fact my favorite) however it could not handle large file pastes to the standard we needed.

Comment: When I run this in IE 8, it only deletes one linebreak at a time (not 2, like your error).  Note:  It doesn't seem to work at all for me in IE 10.